# Will Visual Studio 11 have a native 64bit version?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

As stated here ( [Why is there no 64bit version of Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626823/why-is-there-no-64bit-version-of-visual-studio-2010) ) , Visual Studio 2010 IDE is a 32bit process.
Will the new version of visual studio 11 have a 64bit version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Visual Studio 11 will not have a 64bit version. See also: http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2012/02/23/visual-studio-11-beta-due-february-29th/

Comment: The link you provide does explain nothing about the 64bit version. But I believe your word ;)